# GROUP BY and Mysql 5.7 - wrong grouping

Tags: mysql

My hosting changed mysql version from 5.6 to 5.7 (only_full_group_by disabled) and I got a problem with my query.

```
SELECT  `id`, `category`, `name`, `number`, `lang`
FROM `test`
WHERE `category` = 'Cat1'
ORDER BY FIELD(lang, 'EN', 'JP')
```

This shows good results like this:

```
1 Cat1 Test1 23 EN
2 Cat1 Test2 21 EN
2 Cat1 Test1 23 JP
4 Cat1 Test1 23 JP
5 Cat1 Test2 21 JP
```

Then I am grouping results to get just one, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT  `id`, `category`, `name`, `number`, `lang`
FROM `test`
WHERE `category` = 'Cat1'
ORDER BY FIELD(lang, 'EN', 'JP')
) as table
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY number DESC
```

In mysql 5.6 it worked. In 5.7 not.

Result from 5.6:

```
1 Cat1 Test2 21 EN
2 Cat1 Test1 23 EN
```

Result from 5.7:

```
1 Cat1 Test2 21 JP
2 Cat1 Test1 23 EN
```

Why in mysql 5.7 GROUP BY doesn't take first element, but random one?

Comment: It always took a random element. It just happened to be the first one in your case. It is a [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) behaviour.

Comment: In general, in the absence of any aggregating functions, there should be no GROUP BY clause

Comment: Try to add `LIMIT 1000000` in the subquery. That worked for MariaDB after they "optimized" away the ORDER BY clause in the subqueries. But i can't say, if it works for MySQL 5.7. However this is just a fast fix. You should rewrite all those queries. There are many other ways to solve that problem. And most of them are faster.

Answer (score 2):

Using `GROUP BY` without aggregate function picks values arbitrarily. MySQL doesn't ensure this.

```
SELECT 
T.*
FROM
`test` T
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT  
    MIN(`id`) min_id, 
    `category`,
    `number`
    FROM `test`
    WHERE `category` = 'Cat1'
    GROUP BY `number`
) as t
ON T.`id` = t.min_id AND T.category = t.category AND t.`number` = T.`number`
ORDER BY T.number DESC;
```

**EDIT:**

In order to get a single row for each number under category `Cat1` with `lang='EN'` as highest priority :

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
    *,
    IF(@sameNumber = `number`, @rn := @rn + 1 ,
       IF(@sameNumber := `number`, @rn := 1, @rn := 1)
       ) AS groupWiseRankNumber
    FROM test 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sameNumber := NULL , @rn := 1) var
    WHERE category = 'Cat1'
    ORDER BY `number` , FIELD(lang, 'EN','JP')
) AS t
WHERE t.groupWiseRankNumber <= 1;
```

Comment: The OP's sample data returns three rows, not one.

Comment: But the later query expects one row in the result set.

Comment: Where is lang sorting? :)

Comment: Would you please check the query under edit section? @Matt

Answer (score 1):

You are merely observing what MySQL documentation has said all along:  non-aggregated columns in the `select` of a `group by`query come from *indeterminate* rows.  You should not be using this syntax anyway.  It is a MySQL (mis)feature that simply causes more problems than it solves, and it is not available in any other non-MySQL-derived database.

Here is a method to do what you want that should be much more efficient:

```
select t.*
from test t
where number = 21 and lang = 'EN'
union all
select t.*
from test t
where number = 21 and lang = 'JP' and
      not exists (select 1 from test t2 where t2.number = t.number and t2.lang = 'EN');
```

This can take advantage of an index on `test(number, lang)` for optimal performance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that all ORDER BY will be ignored if they stand in sub-query before GROUP BY in mysql 5.7.

I have the same issue in my query. I found work-around. You can add "ORDER BY" by key column. If `id` is primary key in your table, you can add

```
GROUP BY `id`
```

before

```
ORDER BY FIELD(lang, 'EN', 'JP')
```

Query:

```
`SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT  `id`, `category`, `name`, `number`, `lang`
  FROM `test`
  WHERE `category` = 'Cat1'
  GROUP BY `id`
  ORDER BY FIELD(lang, 'EN', 'JP')
) as table
GROUP BY number
ORDER BY number DESC`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using `limit` in subquery to make `order by` work:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            `id`,
            `category`,
            `name`,
            `number`,
            `lang`
        FROM
            `test`
        WHERE
            `category` = 'Cat1'
        ORDER BY
            FIELD(lang, 'EN', 'JP')
        LIMIT 999999999
    ) AS TABLE
GROUP BY
    number
ORDER BY
    number DESC
```

Or using `GROUP_CONCAT()` to do it:

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    `category`,
    `name`,
    `number`,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            lang
            ORDER BY
                FIELD(lang, 'EN', 'JP')
        ),
        ',',
        1
    ) AS lang
FROM
    `test`
WHERE
    `category` = 'Cat1'
GROUP BY
    number
ORDER BY
    number DESC
```